# Fantasy book about a besieged city

Tags: story-identification, magic, warfare, orcs

I'm looking for a book I've read in the late nineties, though I don't think it was new at that time.

It's fantasy book (orcs, sorcerers, etc.) chronicling the siege of a city. It starts when the city is first attacked and describes in great detail both the various ways in which the city is attacked, and how it is defended.

I remember mostly how complex the story was, and the amount of character development that happened throughout the book. Both were related to how everything kept changing as people reacted to each other's actions. Everything happened in an ever-changing environment, which was described in great detail.

There was one subplot where someone on the side of the attackers went to great lengths to start a plague in the city, and while successful, there was so much else going on that it hardly registered, and the effects were only briefly mentioned from the side of the defenders.

Unfortunately, I mostly remember how much I was impressed by the depth of the structure of the plot, and not much about the plot itself.

It started with the attackers setting up their weapons to besiege the city, and the city countering their first tactics.... and everything just went haywire quickly.

Two more vague details that may be helpful:

I've read the book in German, but assumed it was translated from English. That assumption may or may not be valid.

And I could have sworn the title was something along the lines of "The Raven", or maybe "The Falcon", but while there are many fantasy books having birds in their title, I couldn't find it among them.

Edit: After reading Legend by David Gemmell as recommended by @Cassfrank, I can think of a few differences:

From what I remember, the book started with the siege, which lasted about a year, while Legend spent most of the book preparing the siege which then only took the last quarter of the book and was done within a few weeks.

I also remember the city being completely surrounded, as in cut off, not as being attacked from only one side with people leaving on the other side.

The fantasy elements were also much more pronounced, there were different species, not just different peoples.

The scene about setting up the siege machines as described by the attackers and then having them quickly countered is a perfect fit, though, and is the one reason I can't rule out that I read Legend back then and just misremember virtually everything about it.

That plague, though. I remember (after the siege had already been going on for a while) a sorcerer (or such) on the attackers' side going to a scene of a previous battle (or maybe a cemetery) and use the bodies of the dead to (create a potion to) poison the water.

A few people died, but the plague didn't spread, so it didn't have the intended impact.

Comment: Puts me in mind of _The Drawing of the Dark_ by Tim Powers. But that's more "Renaissance-era urban fantasy" than "high fantasy". Were there any supernatural elements?

Comment: Do you read game franchise books? Warcraft or Warhammer?

Comment: @Spencer The plot summary of Drawing of the Dark sounds like the setting is very similar, but there wasn't a lot of travelling involved, as the city was completely sealed off, and few (if any) were able to get in or out of the city during the siege.
About the supernatural elements - I'd say typical medieval fantast. There were different races (orcs?) among the attackers, and the use of magic. My memory is VERY hazy on that, though.

Comment: @Turbo The book was lent to me by a friend. I didn't have the impression it was part of a series. I'd be surprised if it was a recognisable one like Warcraft or Warhammer.

Comment: Legend by David Gemmell (1984) revolves around one long siege of a fortress. The book weaves in and out of the lives of the defenders and the attack. Like a fantasy version of the Alamo.

Comment: @Cassfrank The description seems to fit. Reading it now. Nothing familiar yet. I should be able to tell one way or another once the siege starts.

Comment: Your mention of complex story makes me think of K.J. Parker but I've only read a few of his books and stories. I don't think there are any races other than human though.

Comment: @Cassfrank I've finished the book and I still can't tell whether it was a different book or I just wasn't paying attention, misunderstood everything and then remembered it wrongly.
There was that scene about preparing the siege machines that were quickly countered, but the poisoned well would fit the plague subplot only if I remembered literally everything about it wrongly.
The tropes and the general plot certainly fit. At the very least, this is very close to the book I was looking for.